# Can anyone please identify this 6 pin SMD A28L integrated circuit or what it does?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image: photo of unknown device on PCB]

I could not find it by the code written on it - A28L.  It is from a headlamp light with lithium battery and I need to replace it.

Comment: Hi! Repair questions like this one are sadly off-topic.

Comment: Try A28; the last character may not be relevant.  Google "SMD code" and use the links to search for that number. Good luck.